# Read outgoing sms from jailbroken Iphone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, sms, jailbreak

I know there are already a few different questions about this topic but my question is slightly different. I am trying to read or intercept outgoing sms's from my jailbroken iPhone 4. Preferably even attempted SMS ie ones that have failed due to no signal etc. The issue I am running into is all the solutions I have seen seem to rely on the SMS database which I do not think gets updated for any messages sent over SMS that are not displayed in the messages app. Examples of this are activation texts for iMessage. Does anyone know what the best way to intercept or read any attempted sms regardless of the messages app? Thanks.

Comment: The best way depends on iOS version and what exactly do you want to achieve. Do you want to also suppress the message? Or only read it? Different iOS versions sometimes have vastly different internals regarding calls and messages. You will have to reverse-engineer stuff, no getting around. Your best bet would be CommCenter as it's a daemon that handles all cellular functions. There're a couple of helpers and wrappers in iOS private frameworks but it all comes down to CommCenter which interacts with baseband directly.

Comment: Preferably I would like to suppress it, however, that is not required, The phone is running IOS 9.3.5. Where could I find some information to read up on how to reverse engineer it /deal the class dumps

Comment: Class dumps will definitely not be enough or would take too much time with trial and error. Class dumps usually enough only for simple private API calls. You need to dig deeper with IDA or similar tool to understand the logic and data flow. CommCenter is at the center of things but there could probably be some higher level component that deals with SMS. CommCenter is all C/C++ and will be vert difficult to understand. IMAgent plugins, for example, are a good place to look at. When I wanted to suppress incoming SMS I injected into one of them.

Comment: As for guides or something, I don't think you will find anything useful apart from how you can load stuff into IDA and find something simple. You need to learn various topics, understand assembly, how languages and compilers interact with assembly (calling conventions, linking), learn inner details of ObjC runtime etc. Then it's all about digging until you find something. With time you will gain an understanding of how iOS works internally, how Apple does things in general and everything will become much clearer.

Comment: I would do some research into Imagent http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/ChatKit.framework